# How can OpenVPN say "wrong credentials" and then work 15 seconds later when I reconnect?

Tags: openvpn

I nearly got a heart attack today. OpenVPN, upon connecting to my VPN on startup, suddenly says "wrong credentials" (not sure if that was the exact phrasing, but it definitely was about the credentials, AKA username/password, being wrong)... after working every day, all day for a long time. And no, my account had not expired.

Less than half a minute later, I was able to connect. With no changes other than the time passing.

How can such things technically happen? If their server was down or something, wouldn't it give a different message, such as "could not establish connection" or something like that?

Comment: Could be a load balancer pointed you to the wrong server.

Comment: We need client configuration (with keys removed) and, probably, the server configuration to answer this. And likely, some logs from both too. (If the server is not under your control it's likely this question is off topic on SF. We anwer concrete computer questions in business here, not just "how that works" and "how that's possible".)

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have some DNS round robin issue. This happens when you have multiple A entries for the same hostname.